# What is the main theological point of Philippians?

Tags: philippians

I learned recently that many of the epistles have a main theological point. For example, the main point of [Ephesians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_to_the_Ephesians) is that the Church is the body of Christ, and that it may bring unity to the world and reconciliation with God. The main point of [Colossians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_to_the_Colossians) is the supremacy of Christ, as he existed before creation. These points can be verified by reading the epistles, or, more briefly, by reading the linked articles on Wikipedia.

This leads me to wonder, what is the main theological point of Philippians? In other words, what is the main theme, from a theological perspective, if there is one?

Comment: Why are you looking for a theological point in a letter that was meant to be pastoral in nature?

Comment: @DavidP Well, precisely for the stated reason: that the epistles before and after (Ephesians, Colossians) have theological points. But if Philippians is different in nature from these two other epistles, then that would make for a good answer.

Comment: Although Philippians and other Epistles *are* pastoral, they touch on themes that are relevant for all Christians.  This is the reason why the Church Fathers chose to include them in the New Testament canon.

Answer (score 1):

The Epistle to the Philippians emphasizes the importance of community and unity in the Church.  He congratulates the Philippians for their care towards others (ch 1) and warns against the heresy, particularly the heresy of the Judaizers (3:1-11).

The introduction to the book in the *Orthodox Study Bible* summarizes:

> Salvation is a dynamic ongoing experience that is not merely personal, but shared among believers.  St. Paul urges the believers in Philippi toward continued unity, humility, selfless generosity, and joy in Christ.